# Create and return list in a method in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a method in which I want to create an empty list, append some values in it and then return that list. My method keeps returning an empty list. What am I doing wrong?

```
(define-struct graph (vertices edges))
(define-struct vertice (name visited))
(define-struct edge (start-vertice end-vertice length))

;I create data for testing here
(define vertices-list2
  (list (make-vertice 0 0)
        (make-vertice 1 0)
        (make-vertice 2 0)
        )
  )

(define edges-list2
  (list (make-edge 0 1 0)
        (make-edge 1 2 0)
        )
  )

(define (find-adj V edge-list)
  (let ((ret '()))
    (cond
      [(empty? edge-list) ret]
      [(eq? V (edge-start-vertice (car edge-list)))
       (begin
         (append ret '((edge-end-vertice (car edge-list))) )
         (find-adj V (cdr edge-list)))
       ]
      [else (find-adj V (cdr edge-list))]
      )
    )
  )

 (define G (make-graph vertices-list2 edges-list2))
 (find-adj 0 (graph-edges G))
```

Comment: All paths through `find-adj` end in either a recursive call to `find-adj`, or they return `ret`, which has just been bound to `'()` two lines earlier. So all calls ultimately return an empty list.

Comment: According to https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._append%29%29, `append` returns a new list; it doesn't modify `ret`. Even if it did, you use neither `append`'s return value nor `ret` after calling `append`.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. But how can I do it then since I have to recursively call find-adj? I would like to return a list of all neighbours, so I have to store them somewhere when I find them and append that list with each recursion.

Comment: Something like `(cons (edge-end-vertice (car edge-list)) (find-adj V (cdr edge-list)))` instead of your `(begin ...)` maybe? Disclaimer: I don't know Scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code. I have some suggestions:

- You don't need a `begin` inside a `cond`, it's implicit.
- Use `equal?` instead of `eq?`, as it's a more general comparison procedure.
- You have to actually *assign* or pass as a parameter the value returned by `append`, otherwise you're doing an empty operation.
- Make sure to *call* `edge-end-vertice`, you were simply appending a list of symbols, not calling a procedure because of the quote at the beginning.
- Very important: the `ret` variable must NOT be redeclared every time the procedure is called, otherwise you'll be overwriting the result on each call.

Remember that `append` and all the other list operations do not modify the list in-place, they just return a new list - and if you don't save it or pass it around as a parameter (which would be preferred in this case), you'll lose the modification. And it's better if you pass `ret` as a parameter, so its value is kept between calls - we can define a helper procedure for that:

```
(define (find-adj V edge-list)
  (define (helper edge-list ret)
    (cond
      [(empty? edge-list) ret]
      [(equal? V (edge-start-vertice (car edge-list)))
       (helper (cdr edge-list)
               (append ret (edge-end-vertice (car edge-list))))]
      [else (helper (cdr edge-list) ret)]))
  (helper edge-list '()))
```

Comment: Thank you again for your help, I really appreciate it. However this code does not work for me. I get error: `define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 1 extra part`

Comment: @Arcane either change the language to something more advanced (preferably use `#lang racket`), or extract the inner helper as a separate procedure, passing `V` also as a parameter

Comment: so there isn't a way while using "Advanced Student" settings?

Comment: @Arcane sure, as I said above: just cut the inner helper procedure and paste it outside - just make sure to also add `V` as a parameter.